# iTerm2 cursor doesn't return to line beginning

Tags: terminal, mac, iterm

I'm not sure if I'm missing some sort of configuration here, but occasionally my cursor is unable to return to beginning of line where command starts. If I press FN+leftArrow, it goes few characters after beginning of command, if I press FN+rightArrow, ot goes way behind end of line. It seems like it thinks that whole line is shifted to the right. See screenshots attached. I was unable to reproduce this on purpose. It happens woth all kind of different commands pretty nondeterministically :-(. Any ideas are welcomed, thanks.
[image: FN + left arrow] 
[image: FN + right arrow]

Matthew

Comment: Does this happen if you use a less heavily modified shell prompt? Try switching to a super vanilla shell setup.

Comment: You mean like plan cmd prompt, not customized one?

Comment: Yes. If this is bash, try something like `for f in ~/.bash{rc,_profile}; do mv "${f}" "${f}.save"; done` and then get a new iTerm2 window. Do you still have the problem after doing that?

Comment: Well, that helped :-). However, is there a way how to keep custom cmd prompt and resolve this issue? I'm still unclear why this is happening. I use customized cmd prmpt: `export PS1="$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 6)\t [\W]$(tput sgr0): "`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So our debugging session has determined it is your prompt customization, not iTerm2. You said your prompt customization is:

```
export PS1="$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 6)\t [\W]$(tput sgr0): "
```

The simple answer is don't use `tput` to customize your prompt. It's the `sgr0` reset command that's likely doing more than you want it to do and screwing up buffered text movements.

Let's try doing this with ANSI codes directly. If you use [an ANSI color scheme setup like this](https://github.com/ianchesal/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/colors.theme.bash) you can try:

```
export PS1="${normal}${bold_blue}\t [\W]${normal}: "
```

That works perfectly for me with Fn-arrow combinations for navigating the line.

`tput` is a neat idea, but it comes from the `ncurses` package which is a very advanced way of doing UIs in command prompt interfaces by exploiting all kinds of terminal stuff. Best to just stick to ANSI here.

Comment: One last thing. I'm trying this prompt, but it gives me error ': bad substitution': `export PS1="${color reset}${color blue bold}\t [\W]${color reset}: "`. Any ideas?

Comment: Well `color` is a function call but you're trying to use it as some sort of variable reference. Try `export PS1="$(color reset)$(color blue bold)\t [\W]$(color reset): "` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I actually didn't import any other scripts from GitHub link. I thought that `color` was actually some sort of command (although it didnt work in bash nor zsh). Now I see it's a function. I'll play with it more and we'll see what I can get working. Thanks for all the help :-).

Comment: If this doesn't work, put a `\[` before each non-printing sequence (i.e. a color code variable) and a `\]` afterward.

Comment: I had the same symptoms without tput. For me the solution was to change e.g. `$BOLD` to `${BOLD}` in the variable references in my PS1:
```RED='\[\033[31m\]'
GREEN='\[\033[32m\]'
YELLOW='\[\033[33m\]'
BLUE='\[\033[34m\]'
MAGENTA='\[\033[35m\]'
CYAN='\[\033[36m\]'
BOLD='\[\033[1m\]'
NORMAL='\[\033[0m\]'
INVERT='\[\033[7m\]'
UNINVERT='\[\033[27m\]'

export PS1="${BOLD}\$(which_newton)${NORMAL}${BOLD}\$(git_branch)${BLUE}\$(gradle_status)\W/${NORMAL} $ "
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, with exactly the same things (iTerm, bash, and tput). I added `$(tput sgr0)` to the front and start a bash sub shell, the problem goes away and `Ctrl + A` and `Ctrl + E` work all properly from then on.